# Vue + Webpack, Alias can't resolve within Script tags

Tags: vue.js, webpack, alias

I'm new to all of this, anyway, I am discovering Vue.js.

Because I don't like the way you point to different parts of a Vue app, I am using Aliases to solve that for me.

In the webpack.config.js file I have the following set up:

```
resolve: {
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
  'styles': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/scss'),
  'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
  'components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
  'directives': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/directives')
  //'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.js',
},
extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
},
```

Now this seems to work in the template and style tags. But not in the script tag. How could I solve this?

```
<template>
  <div class="app">
    <img class="logo" src="~assets/logo.png">
  </div>
</template>
```

and

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import "~styles/variables";
</style>
```

work.

But the following does not work and throws "*Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~directives/inputBus.js'*"

```
<script>
  import {imbputBus} from '~directives/inputBus.js';
</script>
```

Comment: The tilde prefix (`~`) normally only works inside `<style>` or CSS files. I'm curious how you even got it working at all in the `<template>`. In any case, removing the `~` prefix inside `<script>` should allow the path resolution to work.

Comment: So I decided to start a new project and try it again, for some reason it works. Thanks for your answer, it helped me quite a bit!

Comment: Sure, no problem :)